# Reg expression for as3, need to remove any new line or tab from tags

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have some html tags which will occur in my XML, i would like to replace all texts in between the following format of tags

```
<p>            MYTEXT</p>
```

I want the above tags to be converted to

```
<p>MYTEXT</p>
```

by removing the any new line or tab or spaces between them

Please help me out.

Comment: This is a very simple scenario, what have you tried so far and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: ActionScript comes with `ignoreWhitespace` property when parsing xmls: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#ignoreWhitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way:

```
var str:String = "<p>            MYTEXT</p>";
str = str.replace(/\s+/ig, "");
```